# Apply Dynamic Proxy to all the classes in an application

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, proxy, dynamic-proxy

I want to apply the Dynamic Proxy I created to all the classes that are part of my application. But, I also want to be able to use dependency injection (Spring) instead of writing something like MyDynamicProxy.newInstance(new Account());

Where newInstance is:

```
public static Object newInstance(Object object) {             
return Proxy.newProxyInstance(object.getClass().getClassLoader(),object.getClass().getInterfaces(),new LoggingProxy(object));        
}
```

How can I apply Dependency Injection and Dynamic Proxy to all the classes in my application?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(Object, String)` and returning your proxy instance instead of the original bean.

NB if it's just logging you're after, it might be simpler to look into using Spring's AOP support which will allow you to define a simple logging aspect on all Spring managed beans.

Comment: +1 for BeanPostProcessor. Although I wouldn't advise it, it's nice to know there's more than one way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Don't create your proxies manually, use [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) to create your Logging Proxy.

Create a simple Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect{

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    @Pointcut("execution(* *.*(..))")
    public void methodExecution(){
    }

    @Before("methodExecution()")
    public void logBeforeMethod(final JoinPoint joinPoint){
        log.trace("Entering method " + joinPoint.getSignature() + " with args "
            + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
    }

}
```

Now wire the aspect in Spring:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <bean class="aspects.LoggingAspect" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

</beans>
```

Now all your Spring Beans will be proxies and all of their method executions (at leaast those backed by an interface) will be logged.

> **BTW:** Tracing Aspects are covered in
>   [the free Chapter 10](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/Samplechapter10.pdf) of **[AspectJ
>   in Action](http://www.manning.com/laddad2/)** by Ramnivas Laddad